# How to create JSON object in Scala/Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to create the following JSON object in Scala and Play framework, but I am having trouble:

```
{"employees":[
  {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}
]}
```

The data used to create the object comes from a html form (already implemented). So far my code creates the following:

```
val json: JsValue = Json.toJson(formContent)
//returns = {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}
```

How can I add the the key "employees" to this object?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Json.obj("employees"->Json.arr(json))

Comment: I knew it would be something very simple but couldn't figure out. Thanks it works.

Comment: Plz Accept the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Json.obj("employees"->Json.arr(JSON))
```

Comment: How can I update this object to add a new employee? I've tried this approach but it creates a new employee key. 

val newJson = json.as[JsObject] + ("employee" -> Json.toJson(list))

Comment: Json.arr(employeed1).:+(employee2)+...+(employeedn)